# gettext: extract dgettext() strings to domain.po files

Tags: localization, gettext

I have program with multiple domains, some source files contain dgettext() calls with different text domains.

How to extract gettext-strings to multiple .po files? For example, call `dgettext('one', 'Hello')` should go to one.po, and `dgettext('two', 'Bye')` to two.po. xgettext just ignores text domain and puts everything in single file.

Comment: I found a [suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5354360/645186) on how to parse each domain separately. However, this is a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

First you need a way of separating the domains.

For instance, let's say you have a domain for *lib* and one for *app*, then create a shortcut for the `dgettext()` call;

```
_app(msg) -> dgettext("app", msg);
```

and one for the lib domain:

```
_lib(msg) -> dgettext("lib", msg);
```

Add these calls all over your code, like this;

```
show_message(_app("Choose a directory to save your work."));
show_message(_lib("No space left on device."));
```

Remember that you need to call `bindtextdomain()` for both domains when initializing your application.

To extract them you need to specify different keywords to `xgettext` on all the filenames in your source tree that contains these markers:

```
xgettext --keyword=_app -d domain1 filenames...
xgettext --keyword=_lib -d domain2 filenames...
```

Finally, compile both of the .po files into their binary .mo variant and copy/install them to the right location.

Comment: I already knew this solution, as mentioned in the comments of the question, but thanks for the effort.

Comment: If you think that's a workaround I don't think there'll be any solutions to the problem that are non-workarounds. The alternative would be to write your own program that extracts the dgettext() calls, but then you'd pretty much duplicate all the logic of xgettext.

Comment: This is not a solution, but I am going to award the bounty to you, because it will be wasted otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux, use gtranslator program to manipulate *.po and test your *.po files.